# How do I retrieve an existing output channel in a vscode extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have an extension I'm developing for Visual Studio Code 1.55.2, and I am able to create an output channel via something like:

`let dbgChannel = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("IncrementalSearch")`

what I'd like to be able to do is someplace else, retrieve that channel via something like:

`let dbgChannel = vscode.window.getAlreadyCreatedChannel("IncrementalSearch")`

If I call the code in the first example more than once, I get multiple channels with the same name.  I just want to be able to re-use the channel in multiple different scripts.  Seems like there must be an easy way to do this, but I haven't found one.  Thanks for any pointers to where to look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. You have to keep a reference to your `dbgChannel` instance throughout the extension.